TextX Grammer Rule for CStyle Comments
I'm trying to make a textx grammar that will include a the ability to have single line comments like a c/c++ source file. e.g.
//this is a comment 
This is the grammar I have developed to test this. Eventually 'Entry' will contain more than just comment.
Ledger:entries+=Entry;

Entry: Comment;

Comment:/\/\/.*$/;

However when I try to parse the following file
//comment 1
//comment 2

I get this error
textx.exceptions.TextXSyntaxError: file.txt:3:1: Expected Comment => 'omment 2 *'

This is the debug output of the parser
*** PARSING MODEL ***
>> Matching rule Model=Sequence at position 0 => *//comment
   >> Matching rule Ledger=Sequence in Model at position 0 => *//comment
      >> Matching rule __asgn_oneormore=OneOrMore[entries] in Ledger at position 0 => *//comment
         ?? Try match rule Comment=RegExMatch(\/\/.*$) in __asgn_oneormore at position 0 => *//comment
         ?? Try match rule Comment=RegExMatch(\/\/.*$) in __asgn_oneormore at position 0 => *//comment
' at 0 => '*//comment 1*'ent 1
         ?? Try match rule Comment=RegExMatch(\/\/.*$) in __asgn_oneormore at position 13 => omment 1 *//comment
' at 13 => 'omment 1 *//comment 2*'
         ?? Try match rule Comment=RegExMatch(\/\/.*$) in __asgn_oneormore at position 26 => omment 2 *
         -- NoMatch at 26
         -- NoMatch at 26
      <<- Not matched rule __asgn_oneormore=OneOrMore[entries] in __asgn_oneormore at position 0 => *//comment
   <<- Not matched rule Ledger=Sequence in Ledger at position 0 => *//comment
<<- Not matched rule Model=Sequence in Model at position 0 => *//comment

If I add another option to the Entry rule e.g.
Ledger:entries+=Entry;

Entry: Comment | FLOAT;

Comment:/\/\/.*$/;

and add that entry to the file e.g.
//comment 1
//comment 2
7

Then I don't get an exception thrown but comments aren't parsed ( they don't show up in my model). Parser debug output is as follows.
>> Matching rule Model=Sequence at position 0 => *//comment
   >> Matching rule Ledger=Sequence in Model at position 0 => *//comment
      >> Matching rule __asgn_oneormore=OneOrMore[entries] in Ledger at position 0 => *//comment
         >> Matching rule Entry=OrderedChoice in __asgn_oneormore at position 0 => *//comment
            ?? Try match rule Comment=RegExMatch(\/\/.*$) in Entry at position 0 => *//comment
            ?? Try match rule Comment=RegExMatch(\/\/.*$) in Entry at position 0 => *//comment
' at 0 => '*//comment 1*'omment 1
            ?? Try match rule Comment=RegExMatch(\/\/.*$) in Entry at position 13 => omment 1 *//comment
' at 13 => 'omment 1 *//comment 2*'
            ?? Try match rule Comment=RegExMatch(\/\/.*$) in Entry at position 26 => omment 2 *7
            -- NoMatch at 26
            -- NoMatch at 26
            ?? Try match rule FLOAT=RegExMatch([+-]?(\d+(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)([eE][+-]?\d+)?(?<=[\w\.])(?![\w\.])) in Entry at position 0 => *//comment
            ++ Match '7' at 26 => 'omment 2 *7*'
         <<+ Matched rule Entry=OrderedChoice in Entry at position 27 => mment 2 7*
         >> Matching rule Entry=OrderedChoice in __asgn_oneormore at position 27 => mment 2 7*
            ?? Try match rule Comment=RegExMatch(\/\/.*$) in Entry at position 27 => mment 2 7*
            ?? Try match rule Comment=RegExMatch(\/\/.*$) in Entry at position 27 => mment 2 7*
            -- NoMatch at 27
            -- NoMatch at 27
            ?? Try match rule FLOAT=RegExMatch([+-]?(\d+(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)([eE][+-]?\d+)?(?<=[\w\.])(?![\w\.])) in Entry at position 27 => mment 2 7*
            -- NoMatch at 27
         <<- Not matched rule Entry=OrderedChoice in Entry at position 27 => mment 2 7*
      <<+ Matched rule __asgn_oneormore=OneOrMore[entries] in __asgn_oneormore at position 27 => mment 2 7*
   <<+ Matched rule Ledger=Sequence in Ledger at position 27 => mment 2 7*
   ?? Try match rule EOF in Model at position 27 => mment 2 7*
<<+ Matched rule Model=Sequence in Model at position 27 => mment 2 7*

Can anyone help me add c style comments to my grammar that end up in the model?
Thanks!

Retaining comments (and whitespaces) in the model is not available yet in textX (see this issue). Unfortunately, the only option is to capture comments using regular rules, which can clutter your grammar with comment-handling assignments. You can make maintenance slightly easier by restricting where comments can appear in the model, but again, it's not an ideal solution.
